# Maximum swing calculation with clothoid translation and rotation

Tags: matrices, derivatives, trigonometry

I want to calculate the maximum swing of vehicle with a clothoid translation and rotation.

Given a vehicle with rotation point O and rear-right point P with a rotation $\theta$ and translation T on time t the P is:

$$
P_t = \left[ \begin{matrix} x_t \\ y_t \end{matrix} \right]= R(\theta_t)(P_0-O)+O+T_t
$$

$$
P_0 = \left[ \begin{matrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \end{matrix} \right]
$$

$$
O = \left[ \begin{matrix} o_x \\ o_y \end{matrix} \right]
$$

The translation and rotation is given by an approximation of a clothoid function.

$$
T_t=\left[ \begin{matrix}
t-\frac{t^5}{40(rt)^2} \\
\frac{t^3}{6rt} 
\end{matrix} \right]
$$
$$
\theta_t=\frac{t}{2r}
$$

I'm only interested in the vertical minimal (max swing) of:

$$
y_t=(x_o-o_x)\sin\left(\frac{t}{2r}\right)+(y_0-o_y)\cos\left(\frac{t}{2r}\right)+o_y+\frac{t^3}{6rt}
$$

The derivative is:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d}\ t}=\frac{3\sin\left(\frac{t}{2r}\right)o_y+3\cos\left(\frac{t}{2r}\right)x_0 - 3\sin\left(\frac{t}{2r}\right)y_0-3\cos\left(\frac{t}{2r}\right)o_x+2t}{6r}
$$

I like to find the minimum, so:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d}\ t}=0
$$

So, to solve for t:
$$
3\sin\left(\frac{t}{2r}\right)o_y+3\cos\left(\frac{t}{2r}\right)x_0 - 3\sin\left(\frac{t}{2r}\right)y_0-3\cos\left(\frac{t}{2r}\right)o_x+2t=0
$$

But I'm stuck, it seems impossible to solve this for t.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE, you can use the commands `\left` and `\right` in front of brackets to automatically resize them. For example, `$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$` produces $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation cannot be given closed form solution(s).

Nevertheless, it can be brought to a classical form with efficient ways to solve it.

Indeed, starting from :

$$\cos(\frac{t}{2r})(x_0 - o_x)+\sin(\frac{t}{2r})(o_y-y_0)=-\frac{2}{3}t$$

Setting in particular $T=\frac{t}{2r} \iff t=2rT$, this equation can be given the form:

$$A \cos(T)+B\sin(T)=-\underbrace{\frac{4r}{3}}_C T$$

$$\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\cos(T)+\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\sin(T)\right)=-CT$$
$$\underbrace{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}_D\sin(\underbrace{T + \arctan(A/B)}_{\tau})=-CT$$

$$D\sin(\tau)=-C(\tau - \arctan(A/B))$$

which can be given the form $M+e \sin(E)=E$, therefore is a **Kepler equation** for which there are efficient numerical methods of resolution.